# FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] Python os.path.join curses himself (probably)

Tags: python, filenotfounderror

Im new here, just like in Python, so dont chide me for dumb mistakes
Here I think the most attractive part of the code that does not work as it should

```
folder4 = 'game2'
os.chdir(os.path.join(os.curdir, folder4))
```

Here's what kind of error I have

```
**Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\games\Wem extractor\my_version\py_rename.py", line 20, in <module>
    os.chdir(os.path.join(os.curdir, folder4))
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified: '.\\game2'**
```

game2 is in my catalog
Idk what's wrong
Sorry if I gave too little information

Comment: Do you want the current working directory? That's `os.getcwd()` rather than `os.curdir`.

Comment: `os.curdir` is not doing what you think.

Comment: The problem is that the current directory isn't what you think it is.  Specifically, the current directory is **not** necessarily the same directory as the python code script.  You can use `print(os.getcwd())` to see the actual current directory.

Comment: And `chdir()` is interpreted relative to the current directory anyway, so `os.curdir` is useless in this case, even if it did what you think.